# помогите разобратьсяс админкой на laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Мне нужно сделать админку на laravel... Подключил sleepingowl 4!
Делаю по данному видеоуроку (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ca4zn71n4BI), по инструкции с официального сайта совы ВСЕ данные повносил:
файл composer.json:

```
{...
   "require": {
           ...
           "laravelrus/sleepingowl": "4.*@dev"
  }
}
```

файл config/app.php:

```
 'providers' => [
           ...
           SleepingOwl\Admin\Providers\SleepingOwlServiceProvider::class,   
           App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
           ...  ]
```

файл .env:

```
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
 DB_DATABASE=laravel5
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Ввожу в адресную строку http://blog.laravel.com/admin (как сказано в официальных доках http://sleepingowladmin.ru/docs/configuration) выдает:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at blog.laravel.com Port 80
```

Логи апача говорят :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2017:13:01:23 +0200] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 404 502 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0"
```

Помогите настроить админку!

Ссылка на Github:

```
 https://github.com/AlexBukreyev/blog.laravel
```

Comment: А ты точно сделал этот шаг? `$ php artisan sleepingowl:install`

Comment: `php artisan sleepingowl:install

Publishing complete for tag [config]!
Copied Directory [/vendor/laravelrus/sleepingowl/public] To [/public/packages/sleepingowl]
Publishing complete for tag [assets]!
Publish assets: ✔
SleepingOwl Framework successfully installed.`

да, сделал!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все прекрасно, просто пропишите Route:

> ```
> /routes/web.php
> ```

```
<?
        Route::get('/admin', function () {
        return view('admin.index');
    /* только напишите путь к вашей view
    });
?>
```

Comment: а ГДЕ создается вьюха админки?в папке /app/Admin/ ничего похожего на вьюхи  нет...Теоретически, как я понимаю, она должна была бы создаться в resource/views/ ...но там ничего подобного тоже нет...:
email.blade.php, reset.blade.php, login.blade.php, register.blade.php, app.blade.php, home и welcome...В доках написано, что оно автоматически создается.....

Comment: Лежать в моем случае должен resources/views/admin/index.blade.php

Comment: В вашем случае я так понял нужно вывести login.blade.php

Comment: https://laracasts.com/skills/laravel

Comment: return view('register');

Comment: Vasilyuk Dmitry, из-под коробки у меня в папке views/ папка admin/ НЕ появилась....я перенаправил на файл register тоже самое 404 502 ошибка,как говорит апач...у меня вопрос.....сначала нужно регистрацию настроить чтоб админка работала?

Comment: Ай ай, надо запускать через php artisan serve

Comment: Или через homestead

Comment: Если вам возвращает не ошибку laravel, запустите через "php artisan serve"

Comment: Вообще я бы советовал вам запушить ваше детище на github  и мы могли бы вам помочь, а вы бы сделали Merge

Comment: Vasilyuk Dmitry добавил ссылку на гитхаб